# jQuery autocomplete ui with multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I'm trying to work with autocomplete with 3 different inputs.  Each input uses a source which is an array.

The first instance of autocomplete works fine but the other 2 only show the first array item of their corresponding arrays.

My code is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(function() {
    var ACTags = [
        <%
        j=AClistMax
        For i=0 To AClistMax-1
            response.write(chr(34) & AClist(1,i)& chr(34) & ",")
        next
        response.write(chr(34) & AClist(1,j)& chr(34))
        %>
    ];

    $('#AC').autocomplete({
    source: ACTags
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(function() {
    var AHTags = [
        <%
        j=AHlistMax
        For i=0 To AHlistMax-1
            response.write(chr(34) & AHlist(1,i)& chr(34) & ",")
        next
        response.write(chr(34) & AHlist(1,j)& chr(34))
        %>
    ];
    $('#HP').autocomplete({
    source: AHTags
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(function() {
    var OMTags = [
        <%
        j=OMlistMax
        For i=0 To OMlistMax-1
            response.write(chr(34) & OMlist(1,i)& chr(34) & ",")
        next
        response.write(chr(34) & OMlist(1,j)& chr(34))
        %>
    ];
    $('#OM').autocomplete({
    source: OMTags
    });
  });
</script>
```

Inputs are these:

```
<label for="AC"></label>
<input id="AC" name="drug_name" value="<%=session("drug_name")%>"/>

<label for="HP"></label>
<input id="HP" name="drug_name2" value="<%=session("drug_name2")%>"/>

<label for="OM"></label>
<input id="OM" name="drug_name3" value="<%=session("drug_name3")%>"/>
```

Comment: What is the output of AHTags, OMTags, ACTags? You can check that by doing 'View page source'

Comment: The output for ACTags is the correct list.  While typing the autocomplete works correctly but for the other 2 they only show the first row in the array and only if a character you have typed is contained in the value of the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.  It wasn't to do with autocomplete at all.  It turned out that when setting the AHlistMax variable in the setup page I had a transcription error.  i.e. I was passing in a null or a value of 0 for this so it was only reading in the lowest row of the array.

Thank you everyone who helped out.